# Explicit trapezoidal rule

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am studying 'Explicit Methods Based on Quadrature'.

I found that 'Heun's method may refer to the improved or modified Euler's method (that is, the explicit trapezoidal rule)'. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method) for more details.

From what I understood the idea of the explicit trapezoidal rule is to replace the deﬁnite integral on the right-hand side with a numerical approximation.

Where the formula for the main Trapezium rule for a specific differential equation is:

$$ Y_{n+1}=Y_n+\frac{h}{2} \bigg[f(t_n,Y_n)+f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \bigg]+ \mathcal{O}(h^3)$$

So, we are writing the formula $Y_{n+1}$ in terms of $Y_n, t_n $ and $t_{n+1}$.

If I have the function:

$$f(t,y)= \frac{8 \cos(4t)+y}{4}$$

and want to express the above explicit formula that uses the specific RHS of the function $f(t,y)$

Should I express it as following:

$$Y_{n+1}=Y_n+\frac{h}{2} \bigg[\frac{8 \cos(4t_n)+y_n}{4}+\frac{8 \cos(4t_{n+1})+y_{n+1}}{4} \bigg]+\mathcal{O}(h^3)$$

At each step the unknown is $Y_{n+1}$ I am trying to solve for it  in the above equation as an explicit function of $Y_n $ but I am not sure how to do it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you

Comment: The notation you have is confusing, and I think there might be typos in your post. First, you want to calculate the intermediate step $y* = y_{n} + f(t_{n}, y_{n})$ where $$f(t_{n}, y_{n}) = \frac{8 \cos(4t_{n}) + y_{n}}{4}$$ Then you want to calculate $$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} \left[ f(t_{n}, y_{n}) + f(t_{n} + h, y*) \right]$$ which is your value at the $(n+1)^{th}$ step. Just so you know, because your problem is _linear_, you are better off using the implicit trapezoidal rule, which is more stable and also has the added benefit that it's easier to compute.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. I changed the notation

Comment: What you have down for $Y_{n+1}$ is the _implicit_ trapezoidal rule. Not the _explicit_ trapezoidal rule. The $y_{n+1}$ on the RHS should actually be your previously computed step $y*$ (what the wikipedia page has as $\tilde{y}$).

Comment: I am trying to solve for $Y_{n+1}$ as an explicit function of $Y_n$ as I saw in some exercises. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You just want to compute

$$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} \left[ f(t_{n}, y_{n}) + f(t_{n} + h, y_{n} + hf(t_{n}, y_{n})) \right] $$

It's just a matter of replacing the arguments $t$ and $y$ of your function $f$ with $t_{n}, y_{n}, t_{n} + h$ and $y_{n} + hf(t_{n}, y_{n})$. I think you're getting confused with notation. I suggest trying some easier methods on easier problems and getting used to that before trying this problem.

Comment: Yes I am a bit confused, I saw that as you said this is a implicit method(because $Y_{n+1}$ are in both sides of the equation but we can convert it to a explicit method using Euler's method to replace $Y_{n+1}$ on the RHS by: $Y_{n+1}=Y_n+hf(t_n,Y_n)$ 
then we obtain:

$Y_{n+1}=Y_n+\frac{h}{2}f(t_n,Y_n)+ \frac{h}{2}f(t_{n+1},Y_n+hf(t_n,Y_n)$ 

I am just not sure if applying this in my function the answer will be : 

$ Y_{n+1}= Y_n+\frac{h}{2}[(\frac{8cos(4t_n)+Y_n}{4})+\frac{h}{2}(\frac{8cos(4t_{n+1})+Y_n}{4}+h(\frac{8cos(4t_n+Y_n}{4})]$ and this is the explicit formula

Comment: The update you got is wrong. You should have

\begin{align}
f(t_{n}, y_{n}) &= \frac{8 \cos(4t_{n}) + y_{n}}{4} \\
f(t_{n} + h, y_{n}) &= \frac{8 \cos(4(t_{n} + h)) + y_{n}}{4} \\
f(t_{n} + h, y_{n} + hf(t_{n}, y_{n})) &= \frac{8 \cos(4(t_{n} + h)) + y_{n} + hf(t_{n}, y_{n})}{4} \\
&= \frac{8 \cos(4(t_{n} + h)) + y_{n} + h\frac{8 \cos(4t_{n}) + y_{n}}{4}}{4} \\
\end{align}

So

$$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{h}{2} \left[ \frac{8 \cos(4t_{n}) + y_{n}}{4} + \frac{8 \cos(4(t_{n} + h)) + y_{n} + h\frac{8 \cos(4t_{n}) + y_{n}}{4}}{4} \right]$$